# How to scale a rotated rectangle to always fit another rectangle

Tags: algorithm, geometry

the background of my question is the following.
I have a picture and a crop rectangle which describes how the picture should be cropped to produce the resulting picture. The crop rectangle is always smaller or at maximum the size of the picture.
Now it should be possible to rotate the crop rectangle.
This means that when rotating the crop regtanle inside the picture, the crop must be scaled in order that its extends does not exceed the photo.

Can anybode help me with a formula of how to compute the scale of the crop rectanlge based on the axis aligned photo regtancle?

My first attempt was to compute a axis aligned bounding box of the crop rectanlge and than make this fit it the photo rectangle. But somehow i get stuck with this approach,

**Edited:**
One more think to note:
- The crop rectangle can have other dimension and another center point inside the surrounding rectangle. This means the crop rectangle can be much smaller but for example is located at the lower left bound of the picture rectangle. So when rotating the smaller crop it will also exceed its limits

Thanks in advance
Sebastian

Comment: Must crop rectangle have the same proportions as source picture?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you rotate an axis-aligned rectangle of width `w` and height `h` by an angle φ, the width and height of the rotated rectangle's axis-aligned bounding box are:

```
W = w·|cos φ| + h·|sin φ|
H = w·|sin φ| + h·|cos φ|
```

(The notation `|x|` denotes an absolute value.) This is the bounding box of the rotated crop rectangle which you can scale to fit the original rectangle of width `wo` and height `ho` with the factor

```
a = min(wo / W, ho / H)
```

if `a` is less than 1, the rotated crop rectangle fits inside the original rectangle and you don't have to scale. Otherwise, reduce the crop rectangle to the scaled dimensions

```
W′ = a·W
H′ = a·H
```

Comment: Thanks for this. One problem is, that the crop rectangle must not have the same center as the original. For example the crop rectangle can be much smaller but is oriented an the upper left cordern of the surrounding picture rectangle. When rotating the crop arounds its center it will also exceed the picture rectangle. I have no ide how to handle this case. I need to find the scaling factor which also covers this case. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Then your base rectangle must be based on the minimum distance from the crop rectangle's centre to the outer rectangle's border: `wo = 2·min(x - xo - wo/2, xo + wo/2 - x)` where `x` is the centre of the crop rectangle and `xo` is the centre of the oure rectangle. Likewise for `H` and `y`, of course.

Comment: @M Oehm: Or you can explicitly constrain two of corners of the cropped rectangle to lie on the edges of the outer rectangle... Same calc, just a change of perspective. +1, by the way

Comment: Thank you but i am not able to get plausible results. For example let's say the outer rectangle is a quad with it's origin at (0, 0) with a dimension of 1. In that case the center x0 is at 0.5 and wo/2 is always 0.5. For this i am getting negative values for wo for every crop rectangle inside.

Comment: Okay, I see my typo: It's `2·min(x - (xo - wo/2), xo + wo/2 - x)`. `xo - wo/2` is a fancy way to refer to the left edge and `xo + wo/2` is the right edge.

Answer (score 1):

You could start checking if the dimension of the cropped rectangle fit in the old rectangle:

```
bound_x = a * cos(theta) + b * sin(theta)
bound_y = b * cos(theta) + a * sin(theta)
```

Where a and b are the new dimensions, theta us the angle and bound_x and bound_y should be smaller of the original rectangle.