# scaledToFit() does not work when rotationEffect() applied

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to scale the final output view so it lies inside the frame. But looks like this does not work and the edges of the rotated image spill out of the frame. Any idea how this can be fixed?

The bigger question is how to get this to work on any transformation applied so the final view can be scaled to fit a frame.

```
Image(systemName: "trash.slash.fill")
                .resizable()
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(20))
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .border(Color(white: 0.75))
```

[image: code output screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a `scaleEffect` to fit the image into the bounding box.

Based on the information in [How to scale a rotated rectangle to always fit another rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33866535/20386264), I think the scaling factor is computed as `1 / (abs(sin(angle)) + abs(cos(angle)))`:

```swift
let degrees = CGFloat(20)

private var radians: CGFloat {
    degrees * CGFloat.pi / 180
}

var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "trash.slash.fill")
        .resizable()
        .foregroundColor(.green)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(degrees))
        .scaledToFit()
        .scaleEffect(1 / (abs(sin(radians)) + abs(cos(radians))))
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .border(Color(white: 0.75))
}
```

[image: RotatedImage]

Comment: Can you explain the math? I could not come to that formula by looking at the link.

Comment: In this case, the width and height are the same. So there is no need to calculate ```W``` and ```H``` separately and 1 can be used as the original size. Then the formula for ```a``` gives you the scaling factor.