# Changing the image size depending on the degree of rotation?

Tags: swiftui

When adding an image and changing the rotation angle, the background is visible. How can I fix this? Can I make any image selected in the gallery in full screen so that the background is not visible?

```
  import SwiftUI
    import PhotosUI

    struct ContentView: View {

    @State var baseScale: CGFloat = 1.0

    @State var baseRotation: Angle = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                    Image("Image")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                        .rotationEffect(baseRotation)
                        .scaleEffect(baseScale)
            }
            .background(.white)
            .onAppear {
                baseRotation.degrees = 30.0
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can't you use the .onChange(baseRotation) modifier to detect any changes in rotation?

Comment: I can, but I need the image to cover the entire screen at any angle of rotation

Comment: Can you provide a mimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Changed the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exercise is all about trigonometry.

The answer to [How to scale a rotated rectangle to always fit another rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33867165/20386264) provides a formula for computing the size of a rectangle that encloses another rotated rectange. In your case, the formula needs to be used in reverse: the inner rectangle represents the screen, the outer rectangle is the scaled image.

To calculate the scaling factor, the following inputs are needed:

- the size of the screen
- the angle of rotation
- the aspect ratio of the image (width/height).

The size of an image can be read from a `UIImage`, but not from an `Image`. However, I think your question originally used a `UIImage`, so hopefully it is not a problem for you to read the image size and compute the aspect ratio.

The following example uses two system images with quite different aspect ratios:

- a standing figure, with aspect ratio slimmer than the display
- a tortoise, with aspect ratio wider than the display.

Since the size cannot be read from an `Image`, the width/height ratio is hard-coded (which is sufficient for example purposes).

```swift
enum TestImage: String {
    case figure = "figure.stand"
    case tortoise = "tortoise.fill"

    var name: String {
        "\(self)".capitalized
    }

    var imageName: String {
        self.rawValue
    }

    var color: Color {
        self == .figure ? .red : .green
    }

    // width / height
    var widthHeightRatio: CGFloat {
        self == .figure ? 0.4284 : 1.9782
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var angleDegrees: CGFloat = 0
    @State var selectedImage = TestImage.figure

    private var angleRadians: CGFloat {
        angleDegrees * .pi / 180
    }

    private func scalingFactorToFill(screenSize: CGSize) -> CGFloat {
        let w = screenSize.width
        let h = screenSize.height
        let initialImageHeight = (w / h) < selectedImage.widthHeightRatio
            ? h
            : w / selectedImage.widthHeightRatio
        let initialImageWidth = initialImageHeight * selectedImage.widthHeightRatio

        let absCos = abs(cos(angleRadians))
        let absSin = abs(sin(angleRadians))

        let widthToFill = (w * absCos) + (h * absSin)
        let heightToFill = (w * absSin) + (h * absCos)

        let scalingFactorWidth = widthToFill / initialImageWidth
        let scalingFactorHeight = heightToFill / initialImageHeight
        return max(scalingFactorWidth, scalingFactorHeight)
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Image(systemName: selectedImage.imageName)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .foregroundStyle(selectedImage.color)
                .background { Color(white: 0.9) }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                .scaleEffect(scalingFactorToFill(screenSize: geometry.size))
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(angleDegrees))
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
                Picker("Test image", selection: $selectedImage) {
                    Text(TestImage.figure.name)
                        .tag(TestImage.figure)
                    Text(TestImage.tortoise.name)
                        .tag(TestImage.tortoise)
                }
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                Slider(value: $angleDegrees, in: 0...360)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .padding(.bottom, 100)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .background(.yellow)
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

The background to the main content would be yellow, but it is not being seen -> this was the objective. If you change `scalingFactorToFill` to return the `min` scaling factor, instead of the `max` scaling factor, then it works more like scaledToFit. Then the yellow is seen!

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to play around with the scale when rotating the image. My soolution would be this, I've placed a Slider for testing purpoeses to rotate the image faster:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var baseScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var baseRotation: Angle = .zero
    @State private var rotation: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Image(.pic1)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                    .rotationEffect(baseRotation)
                    .scaleEffect(baseScale)
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                Slider(value: $rotation, in: 0...360) {
                    Text("Rotation")
                } minimumValueLabel: {
                    Text("0")
                } maximumValueLabel: {
                    Text("360")
                }
                .padding()
                .onChange(of: rotation) { oldValue, newValue in
                    print("New value: \(newValue)")
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.1)) {
                        if newValue != 0 && newValue != 360 {
                            baseScale = 1.1
                        } else {
                            baseScale = 1
                        }
                    }
                    baseRotation.degrees = newValue
                }
                
            }
            .background(.white)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

You also need to ignore the safe area for the GeometryReader in this case. This alone would solve many of the issues you are facing.
What I did was simply to increase the scale when the rotation was different from 0 or 360.
Let me know if this can work for you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the base size does not increase depending on the angle of degrees, the image does not cover the entire screen and the background is visible

Comment: I don't have access to your image for testing. I used my own image. If you can provide your sample image I can do some testing with it.